# Remove "random" noise

Tags: gimp, image-compression

I have a picture which was taken from a book and it's full of noise:
[image]

I tried to remove the noise manually but it is too difficult and takes a lot of time.
I noticed some webpages who attempt to treat the noise problem:
http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Reducing_CCD_Noise/
http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Selective_Gaussian_Blur/
But it is different than my type of noise.

Do you have any idea on how to remove this type of noise? With GIMP if possible.

Comment: It's not *noise*, it's compression artifacts and doesn't seem closely related to photography.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is about cleaning up a graphic. Should be moved to graphicdesign.stackexchange.com

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are jpeg artifacts and what can be done about them?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/19270/what-are-jpeg-artifacts-and-what-can-be-done-about-them)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are seeing in your example is not random noise. It is what is referred to as *compression artifacts* and is what happens when an image is compressed too much to make the file size smaller.

Instead of trying to use noise removal, simply use a levels or curves layer.  Or even try just boosting the contrast.  You have a white background and dark text and lines, and the noise is a light or middle grey, so any of those methods can be adjusted to remove the lighter tones and make them white.

For example, quickly using pixlr and boosting contrast, I get this result.  I'm sure you can do better with GIMP and levels or curves

[image]

Using a curve:

[image]