# What is causing these artifacts in a photo of lightning?

Tags: photo-editing, sensor

What are the almost pixelated edges in this photo called? What would cause it? The photo is cropped so it stands out more. I find it often happens with highlights with softer edges. You may need to zoom in. I'm not sure if it's a sensor thing or my camera settings or my very low skill levels at editing or maybe a size problem .. I shoot in raw and my camera is a canon 6D with a Samyang 14mm f2.8.

[image]

Comment: And which photo is that, now?

Comment: If you come back to add the photo, it might be worth reconsidering your question title too. This shouldn't be an afterthought - the question title is the most important bit - how else will that person with the answer be tempted to click on your question in particular?

Comment: Sorry all .. newbi here my first post I have re edited and added the photo

Comment: The square 8x8  pattern (along the white lines, but also elsewhere) hints at JPEG compression artefacts. The JPEG quality of that image is 91 but it could have been much less in a former life. There is also a tremendous amount of banding.

Comment: Is that lightning? Can you highlight exactly what you mean by "pixelated edges"?

Comment: What application are you using to convert the raw image data to jpeg?

Comment: @mattdm  yes it's lightning you will see it better if your screen brightness is up and if you zoom in a bit

Comment: @michael c editing and conversion is in luminar 2018 when editing it dose not show up much at all but after resize and conversion (resize aprox  around 2040×1300 pixels ) it will show up a lot more if it's added to facebook or saved to my phone .. I can also see it on my pc on Facebook

Comment: Does [What are jpeg artifacts and what can be done about them?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/19270/what-are-jpeg-artifacts-and-what-can-be-done-about-them) help?

Comment: thank You for editing and uploading the photo. Reopen vote and +1 from me

Comment: @Matthew Anything with a file size greater than about 150KB will be severely recompressed by facebook. That's facebook reducing their bandwidth demands. If you want your facebook viewers to see it without having the snot compressed out of it, post a link to another photo hosting site.